# MVC how to cast long into string in ViewData Dropdownlist

Tags: asp.net-mvc, drop-down-menu, viewdata

```
ViewData["dropDown_ViewOwnerShare"] = correspondingDropDownValue.Select(j => new SelectListItem { Text = j.ListOfValue, Value = j.ListOfValue, Selected = j.ListOfValue == x.DefaultValue }).ToList();
```

Base on the above code, the viewdata["dropDown_e"] which is a dropdownlist successfully been generated. And now for each of the element, instead of using j.ListOfValue as Value, I want to use j.UserID as Value. Problem is j.UserID is a long type returned from database and Value is always expecting a string. I've tried j.UserID.ToString() but it has compile error. May I know how should I handle it?

Comment: What's the compile error

Comment: @Rikon, LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'String.String ToString()' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is a type of `correspondingDropDownValue`? Suppose it's `IQueryable<T>`, right? At first, you need to get all required fields from the database, then cast result to `IEnumerable<T>` and only then - create `SelectListItems` list. Something like this:

```
    correspondingDropDownValue
    .Select(j => new {Value = j.UserID, Text = j.SomeTextField}) // SELECT UserID, SomeTextField FROM SomeTable
    .AsEnumerable()       // Evaluate the query
    .Select(j => new SelectListItem // Work with in-memory objects using LINQ to Objects instead of LINQ to Entities
    {
        Value = j.Value.ToString(),
        Text = j.Text,
        Selected = j.Value == x.DefaultValue
    })
    .ToList()
```